# SPREADSHEET INDIRECT() with variable column

Tags: google-sheets, formula, spreadsheet

If `A1` has a value of `2`, `=INDIRECT("L"&(5+A1))` will return me cell `L7`'s content. And my `A1` value keeps on being updated.

But I need a way to sort through columns instead of rows, like
`L7`, `M7`, `N7`, `O7` and so on...

Which formula can help me sort through the columns? I also know that `=COLUMN()` returns the current column converted to number, but I had no luck with `=INDIRECT((column()+A1)&7)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the address() function inside indirect. Address() returns a cell reference as a string. So for example, if you enter in G5

```
=indirect(address(A1, column()))
```

while A1 is 1 the above formula will return the contents of cell G1.
See if this helps?

Comment: please marry me :v